# gtkmm, how can I make my program waiting the clicked signal from a button?

Tags: c++, linux, gtkmm

I want to make my program waiting until a button is clicked.

The problems are,

- I can't use trhead
- I can't use a dialog or another window
- I cant't use a function like `Glib::usleep()` because it makes the interfaces insensitive.

I don't found any strategy to solve that problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution:

```
// computation going on
while( Gtk::Main::events_pending() )
Gtk::Main::iteration();
// computation continued
```

https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Main.html#a2a2a6cddef82f8c52026790f3f7887e0

any comment, or other answer are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything against using the event-based way of Gtkmm, i.e. connecting a listener to the clicked signal of the button?

This would look something like this:

helloworld.h

```
class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window
{

// ...

protected:
  //Signal handlers:
  void on_button_clicked();

  //Member widgets:
  Gtk::Button m_button;
};
```

helloworld.cc

```
// ...
HelloWorld::HelloWorld()
: m_button("Hello World")   // creates a new button with label "Hello World".
{
  // ...

  // When the button receives the "clicked" signal, it will call the
  // on_button_clicked() method defined below.
  m_button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &HelloWorld::on_button_clicked));


  // ...
}

void HelloWorld::on_button_clicked()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Full example is available [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-helloworld.html.en).

Basically, in HelloWorld::on_button_clicked you would then do the action that had to wait until the button was clicked.

Comment: "Is there anything against using the event-based way of Gtkmm, i.e. connecting a listener to the clicked signal of the button?" The problem does not come from here, I can detect the clicked signal (I use the `signal_clicked()` as you did in your example), but I don't know how to make my program waiting for that signal. Anyway thank you